# Returning checkbox value from datagridview to form in c#

Tags: c#, checkbox, datagridview, return

i am trying to get checkbox value from dataGridView1 on double click, every field is working perfectly except the checkbox, so what i need is that when a user check i want to be able to return that check from the dataGridView1 to the form please check my code.

```
private void dataGridView1_MouseDoubleClick_1(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
    {
        //All is working perfect here return from datagridview1
        to each text box
        DataGridViewRow dr = dataGridView1.SelectedRows[0];
        textBox1.Text = dr.Cells[0].Value.ToString();   //id
        textBox2.Text = dr.Cells[1].Value.ToString();   //name
        textBox3.Text = dr.Cells[2].Value.ToString();   //age
        comboBox1.Text = dr.Cells[3].Value.ToString();  //day
        comboBox2.Text = dr.Cells[4].Value.ToString();  //month
        comboBox3.Text = dr.Cells[5].Value.ToString();  //year
        textBox4.Text = dr.Cells[6].Value.ToString();   //reference
        textBox5.Text = dr.Cells[7].Value.ToString();   //weight
        textBox6.Text = dr.Cells[8].Value.ToString();   //height
        textBox7.Text = dr.Cells[9].Value.ToString();   //phonenumber
        textBox8.Text = dr.Cells[39].Value.ToString();  //address
        comboBox4.Text = dr.Cells[40].Value.ToString();  //gender
        textBox9.Text = dr.Cells[35].Value.ToString();  //insurance
        textBox10.Text = dr.Cells[36].Value.ToString(); //profession
        textBox11.Text = dr.Cells[37].Value.ToString(); //email
        dateTimePicker1.Text = dr.Cells[38].Value.ToString();   //datepicker
        textBox12.Text = dr.Cells[10].Value.ToString(); //question1
        textBox13.Text = dr.Cells[11].Value.ToString(); //treatment
        textBox14.Text = dr.Cells[12].Value.ToString(); //allergies
        textBox15.Text = dr.Cells[13].Value.ToString(); //surgicaloperations

        //my problem is here. datagrid view is returning true or false
        // i want it to return check or unchecked for checkbox
            checkBox1.Text = dr.Cells[14].Value.ToString();
            checkBox2.Text = dr.Cells[15].Value.ToString();
            checkBox3.Text = dr.Cells[16].Value.ToString();
            checkBox4.Text = dr.Cells[17].Value.ToString();
            checkBox5.Text = dr.Cells[18].Value.ToString();
            checkBox6.Text = dr.Cells[19].Value.ToString();
            checkBox7.Text = dr.Cells[20].Value.ToString();
            checkBox8.Text = dr.Cells[21].Value.ToString();
            checkBox9.Text = dr.Cells[22].Value.ToString();
            checkBox10.Text = dr.Cells[23].Value.ToString();
            checkBox11.Text = dr.Cells[24].Value.ToString();
            checkBox12.Text = dr.Cells[25].Value.ToString();
            checkBox13.Text = dr.Cells[26].Value.ToString();
            checkBox14.Text = dr.Cells[27].Value.ToString();
}
```

Comment: If it's true, that means the `CheckBox` is checked, if it's false then it is unchecked. So what issue are you having with those results?

Comment: You possibly want this:
`checkBox1.Text =  dr.Cells[14].Value? "Checked": "Unchecked";`

Comment: @Draken i want if a person has ticked the checkbox, when i double click on the datagridview1, the datagridvew1 should return those ticks, it is returning everything except the ticks just says true or false

Comment: You want to return the icons? Why would you want to do that and put that into a text field?

Comment: i want it to return a checkedbox if checked and unchecked box in not checked, i want that in order to revise the form for later use or to update... so yes i want it to return the icons for your question, thx for the help btw

Comment: You can just use the boolean flag to set a checkbox later on: E.g.

`boolean storedValue = dr.Cells[14].Value;` and then later on `CheckBox checkBox = new CheckBox(); checkBox.checked = storedValue;`

Comment: i'm getting an error on first statement with `boolean storedValue = dr.Cells[14].Value;` cannot implicitly convert type object to bool. an explicit conversion exists

Comment: Sorry, that should be `boolean storedValue = dr.Cells[14].Checked;`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you should use

```
checkBox1.Checked
```

instead of

```
checkBox1.Text
```

Comment: its giving an erro : cannot implicitly convert type 'string' to 'bool'
(in the database defenition the checkboxes are defined as bit)

Comment: dr.Cells[14].Value witout converting .ToString()

Comment: also getting same error without converting to string :/

Comment: use Convert.ToBoolean(dr.Cells[14].Value)

Comment: 100% WORKING !!! MY FRIEND YOU ARE AMAZING THANK YOU VERY APPRECIATED ! i returns checkedboxes for all checked , this is what i had in mind